# Is there a way to adjust this popup drain stopper, or is it defect?

Tags: plumbing

I just installed a new pop-up click clack drain for our glass bathroom sink. The only problem is that it doesn't pop up and down anymore. It did when I first took it out of the box. Here is a similar product of what it looks like:

[image]

Am I able to adjust it somehow? Did I forget something when I installed it? Or it is defect?

Answer (score 2):

So I took it back to the store I bought it from and told them the pop up doesn't work anymore. They told me that the spring could be defect and he put in a new spring. Now it works! He told me that he's had 2 that were defect and he showed me how I could take out the spring myself.